# Volume of solid generated by rotating about an axis

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

What is the volume of the solid made by rotating the region bounded by $y=x^2+1$ and $y=-2x+3$ about the $x$ - axis.

Please show the process using:

(i) disks/washers

(ii) cylindrical shells

Comment: Have you tried to solve the question on your own already? If so, what have you tried? I could give you the solution but that would help you nothing. I'd rather see you try to solve it on your own. People here will be more than happy to help and/or guide you if you show that you want to learn rather than just get an answer.

Comment: Hint: for (i) recall that the volume of one of these washers is $(\pi R^2-\pi r^2)h$, where $R$ is the major (largest) radius, $r$ is the minor (smaller) radius and $h$ is the height. For (ii), recall the volume formula for a cylindrical disk, $V=2\pi rxh$.

Comment: thank you. i got around 165,42 cubic units using washers but i keep on getting negative answers using shells. I got ∫_1^(5-2√3)▒〖y(2√(y-1)〗)dy+∫_(5-2√3)^(5+2√3)▒y((3-y)/2-√(y-1))dy. Please tell me where i got wrong

Answer (score 0):

[image: The rotated region]

The photo shows the region to be rotated. The first step is to find the limits on the $x$-axis, namely the solution to $x^2+1=-2x+3$. This can be written $x^2+2x=2$. Complete the square to get $(x+1)^2=3$, so the limits are $x=-1-\sqrt{3}$ and $-1+\sqrt{3}$.

Now imagine a vertical slice. It will have a CD shape (or washer) where the outer radius is the line $-2x+3$ and the inner radius is the curve $x^2+1$. The width will just be $dx$.

Thus our integral will be $\int\limits_{-1-\sqrt{3}}^{-1+\sqrt{3}}\pi((-2x+3)^2-(x^2+1)^2)dx$.

As for the second method, you will need to use the volume of a cylindrical shell, $2\pi rh\Delta r$. I won't do the whole problem, but you have the $x$ limits, and it shouldn't be too different from the first part.